# Match Regex by NOT beginning of String?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of a score between two people. The database I'm pulling these scores from puts a dash between the scores... So normally the score would look something like:

```
2-3
```

I am trying to split these two scores into a `String[]` in Java.

```
match.get("scores").toString().split("-", 1)
```

The problem is, what happens if the scores are negative:

```
-2--3
```

What I would need to do now is split by the first dash it finds that ISN'T the first character in the string.

How would I change my `.split(RegEx, 1)` so that I can match the dash as not the first character?

Comment: Not an answer, but this is a typical violation of proper database design. The scores should be in two separate columns. If you have the option of fixing the schema, do that.

Comment: I agree... but its not my database. Its Challonge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split using this:

```
.split("(?<=\\d)-");
```

`(?<=)` is a positive look-behind. Just google `positive-lookbehind regex` and you should find plenty of information about it.

Comment: Just to add some explanation, this regex means: "split on `-` only if it has digit before it (and don't treat that digit as delimiter)". This part of regex `(?<=...)` is called look-behind and we can read more about it for instance here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind